# Putting Excel Charts Into PowerPoint through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to paste charts from Excel into Powerpoint and actually loop through these charts so that each chart is pasted onto the respective slide. Then move onto the next and so on.

My code so far actually pastes the names of participants in cells and loops through them. I have looked for a code to do this and there are answers on here which help but I do not know how to integrate them to work in this situation, where I am working through PowerPoint VBA and selecting the charts from Excel.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

``

```
Public Sub test()
Dim excelSht As Worksheet
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Set excelApp = GetObject(, "excel.application")
Set excelSht = excelApp.ActiveSheet
Dim path As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With 
Set Rng = excelSht.Range("A2:A11") 
    For Each shp In Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).Shapes
        If shp.Name Like "Title 1" Then shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dear " & cel.Value & vbCrLf & "hello there! blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah " & cel.Value & vbCrLf & "thanks!" 
    Next
    Application.Presentations(1).SaveAs (path & "\" & cel.Value & ".pptx")
Next
End Sub
```

``

So let us say there are 10 charts there. How can I somehow add to this code in order to also loop through the charts and add them one by one to these ppt files on a certain slide where I have left the proper placeholder for a chart?

Thanks tons for your help.

Comment: From your sample, it appears that you're trying to merge data to PowerPoint. There are Add-ins available that already do that: http://www.pptools.com/merge/index.html and http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/Simple_merge.html

Comment: Thanks I'm looking into these now! However, if there is any code you/anyone know(s) it'd be awesome. But I'll try this maybe it'll even save a lot of time and effort! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, so I tried PPTMerge, sadly it adds random characters and stuff to the slides so it is no good :( I cannot purchase the paid version right now. Would you have any code solutions in mind? Thank you.